# Create xml with DataSet tables

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, xsd, dataset

I have created xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Extension">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="parent">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="parentItem">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="child">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" default="10" name="childItem" type="xs:integer" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to load this schema into DataSet and then edit and create xml

so I try to fill childItem element with value 100:

```
  DataSet a = new DataSet();
  a.ReadXmlSchema(mySchema);
  a.Tables[3].Rows.Add(100);
```

then I perform:

`a.getXml()` - result:

```
<Extension xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="test">
  <childItem xmlns="">100</childItem>
</Extension>
```

As you can see its completly ignore schema relations - in the schema you can see that every parent element above childItem is required so if I add value into the deepest children I expect xml like:

```
<Extension>
   <Parent>
      <ParentItem>
        <Child>
          <ChildItem>100<ChildItem/>
        <Child/>
      <ParentItem/>
   <Parent/>
<Extension/>
```

Am I missing something, or this is standard behaviour of DataSet? Thanks a lot
I am using c# and net4.0, winforms

Comment: What does mySchema look like? Is your schema above in a file?

Comment: mySchema is schema above

Comment: No, I mean I want to see how your defining the variable mySchema. Is it a stream? A string path to a file name? xmlReader?

Answer (score 1):

This is the DataSet structure; unless you follow the hierarchy, and provide the IDs approapriately, you will not get the output you want. There's [also a reason](http://paschidev.com/Whitepapers/Deriving_DataSet_from_XML_Schema.html) why you don't see an **Extension** entity, in case you thought about it.

[image]

Since you're inserting only **100**, where the structure of the table is two columns, you get for  *child_Id* a NULL value. The column allows for nulls, so the insert passes since a null value satisfies a foreign key constraint.

To check, if you do:

```
 a.Tables[3].Columns[1].AllowDBNull = false;
```

before your Add, you'll see this error:

```
Error line 11:      a.Tables[3].Rows.Add(100);
Column 'child_Id' does not allow nulls.
```

If you then do:

```
a.Tables[3].Rows.Add(100, 0);
```

You get:

```
Error line 11:      a.Tables[3].Rows.Add(100, 0);
ForeignKeyConstraint child_childItem requires the child key values (0) to exist in the parent table.
```

The problem then seems to be that the referential integrity columns added by the tool allow for null - there is no option to overcome that behaviour.

Comment: DataSet.EnforceConstraints is turned on. in my schema I have defined minoccures - doesnt it mean that they have to be included as parent (ParentItem for example)?

Comment: if I try to validate DataSet.getXml() result as I wrote above against mySchema it isnt valid either. So I suppose that DataSet.ReadXmlSchema change schema and than create xml based on this changed schema